# Magento 2.3.0 - SendGrid Email Delivery Module issue

Tags: module, error, email, third-party-module, magento2.3.0

I have installed "**SendGrid Email Delivery**" module on my magento (2.3.0 version) application. It installed successfully but when I tried to access it from admin panel to configure their settings after clicking on setting link. **It's throwing error - The message should be an instance of \Zend_Mail.**

[image]

Error screen : -

[image]
Is this module not compatible with Magento version 2.3 or what could be issues behind this?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you fix this issue?kindly help me with this issue.

Comment: See Aitoc solution for your problem [Magento 2 SendGrid integration](https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-sendgrid-integration.html). Extension if fully compatible with magento 2.3.x versions Hope it was useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the Magento marketplace link of this module, I see that it's not compatible with Magento 2.3 as of this moment

https://marketplace.magento.com/sendgrid-email-delivery-simplified.html

Comment: Yes, this the same marketplace module link.

Comment: I am also facing same issue after upgrading magento version from 2.2.7 to 2.2.8.Does this compatible with 2.2.8?